# IIS6 Application Pool: App breaks until recycled

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been experiences some problem with website that use ASP.net MVC or Webform.

Problem: Sometime the website isn't showing. If I go to the website, I'll get the Directory Browsing is not permitted or something as such.

Quick fix: Log into the server and did a app pool recycle on the app that is associated with the website.

Sever: Win2k3 Standard R2, IIS6, 4GB RAM, AMD dual core. used it for some share hosting. not many active websites and the traffic is rather low.

I don't quite understand why the website just not working and I have to recycle the app pool. I've created a app pool named ASPNET4 for any website that use .Net 4 and a ASPNET2 for below .Net 4 framework. Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix it instead of checking the website in order to find out.

**Edit:**
I should further explain that this server is used for shared hosting and I'm using Helm3 control panel which created ASPNET2 for .Net 3 and below website and ASPNET4 which I created to support .Net4, and manually associate the website with that pool

Answer (score 0):

If all the websites don't share the same code, create one App Pool per website, and put each website in its own app pool.

That'll help narrow down the site which breaks. You didn't include a history, so it's unclear how long this has been happening. You might find events in the Application event log that help you piece together a timeline of events, and whether some odd/weird exceptions occur immediately prior to this.

When you recycle, you're terminating an old worker process (W3WP.EXE) and replacing it with a new one. That's why it works afterwards.

As to why it breaks - you'll have to check the website to find out. In my experience, W3WPs don't typically break that way; it's something to do with the apps or modules in your website (or their interaction with system-level components, like AV).

Next time, get a memory dump of the process before you recycle it (go get DebugDiag 1.2), and see if you can glean any useful information from it. Alternatively, contact the developer and/or Microsoft support, to help examine the dump and try to establish a root cause.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should further explain that this server is used for share hosting and I'm using Helm3 control panel which created ASPNET2 for .Net 3 and below website and ASPNET4 which I created to support .Net4 and manually associate the website with that pool.

Comment: I don't think that changes anything in the answer (no experience with Helm) - if you can't tell which app is crashing the pool, divide and conquer.